# How to have a static sidebar without using frames?

Tags: javascript, html

My php functions need to do some work with the database to generate the sidebar content, so I want to load it just once. Plus I've read that one should avoid using frames. So what should I do? Use ajax / synchronous-jax?

Comment: "static" in what context, the whole session or for each page? Also, what is your definition of static?

Comment: By static I mean that "load it (the sidebar) just once" for every session. And then as the user clicks on links, the sidebar remains there without being reloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the simplest and plainest way to pull this off is to use frames. This is pretty much what frames were made for. The only real concern is search engine optimisation, so if that's not an issue (say, you're making an administration panel) then go with the frames. If you're using this for a public website then you should probably look for another way of doing it.

You could also just cache the sidebar on the server so it doesn't matter how many times it's loaded. That would sort of avoid the whole issue, don't u think?

Comment: It's a public website and I want SEO. Caching is good, but I don't know how to do it, maybe I'll store the content of sidebar in session variable. What's your opinion on using ajax?

Comment: "using ajax" would affect your entire site, as it would be everything **except** the sidebar that would be loaded with Ajax. There are many ways to cache the sidebar. The most simple one I can think of would be to activate query caching on your SQL server, which removed the strain of running the same query repeatedly. Alternatively you could just save the HTML of the sidebar in a static HTML file which you update regularly.